# DELETE request using WP REST API

Tags: rest-api, json, python

I am trying to delete a post (by ID number) using WordPress' REST API (through python). However, i keep getting this error.

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

I have tried several methods such as:

```
import requests
user='admin'
password='mypassword'
credentials = user + ':' + password
token = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode())
header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),'Content-Type': 'application/json','User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
url='https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/car'

######

#method1 (Delete request)
r=requests.delete(url,headers=header,json={"id":22091})

#method 2(Get with force=True)
r=requests.get(url+'{22091}?force=True',headers=header)
```

I got same error for both methods.

My diagnosis is that the URL I am trying to request through the API does not accept the delete method.(as defined in mywebsite.com/wp-json/)

I've looked for available methods online to add the DELETE method to to the URL however I only found JS code which I'am not completely familiar with and I don't want to risk sending wrong code as I might mess up something.

Presuming my diagnosis is correct,can anyone propose a solution (preferably in python) to add the DELETE method to the url (https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/car) in my wp-json settings.

Comment: I'd guess it's /wp-json/wp/v2/car/22091, with the ID in the URL. Assuming you've registered the post type with [show_in_rest true](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#show_in_rest) - can you read cars over the REST API? I think you'd have to DELETE an URL that also works with GET.

Comment: It worked,thanks. As per suggestion, i added r=requests.delete('https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/car/22091',headers=header), hence just adding the id to the url and running requests.delete.